# Reading a text file stuck in a loop in java

Tags: java, jsp

I'm working on creating a program that reads from a text file that is stored on a server. I'm able to read the file and get my results in the console like the way I want, but when I try to display them on a webpage I'm getting a completely different result. The results I get on the console is

```
Log File Path: the path is here
Input Directory: the input directory
Results Directory: the results directory
```

and on the webpage I'm getting

```
Log File Path: the path is here
Log File Path: the path is here
Log File Path: the path is here
Input Directory: the input directory
Input Directory: the input directory
Input Directory: the input directory
Results Directory: the results directory
Results Directory: the results directory
Results Directory: the results directory
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
  <%

        File file = new File("the file path");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String st;


        while((st = br.readLine()) !=null){
            System.out.println(st);

        %>
        <form action="performMagic('<%=mr.getKey()%>')" method="post"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Log File Path:<%=st%><br>
            Input Directory:<%=st %><br>
            Results Directory:<%=st %><br>
        </form>
        <br>

    </ul>

    <%

        }
        br.close();
    %>
```

It has to do with something about my while loop and I can't figure out what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your "br.close();" statement appears to inside your while loop.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the code. Originally the `br.close()` is outside the loop instead of being inside. With in being inside the loop it only displays the first line in the text nth of times.

Comment: I see. What is before this code section? Are you sure any code executed before or after the part you presented is not effecting your output?